# Что делать, если на Android завис виджет?

Tags: android

Собственно, что делать, я знаю, и ежу понятно, что виджет надо перезагрузить, но мой виджет зависает не по моей ошибке. Он может зависнуть просто так в любой момент времени и не отвечать на нажатия. Я считаю, что это какие-либо ошибки самой системы. В таких случаях обычно на виджетах появляется кнопка перезагрузки виджета, но как это реализовать, чтобы при зависаниях появлялась такая кнопка?!!!

Comment: > мой виджет зависает не по моей ошибке

И почему же вы так решили?

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации вини систему (с)

Comment: Потому что виджет очень простой, там нету ничего особенного. Уже всё было перепроверено, зависаний с моей стороны не может быть. Виджет может зависнуть, когда телефон в заблокированном состоянии. Никаких операций на заднем фоне он не выполняет. Свои функции выполняет по нажатию на него, далее он выводит результат и после этого зависаний не обнаруживается. Они абсолютно спонтанны и происходят в любой момент времени. Ещё есть мысли, что ошибка на моей стороне?

Comment: И вы, конечно же, уже и отладчиком цеплялись к процессу виджета и смотрели, что именно с ним происходит?

Comment: Да, в этот момент я мониторил через logCat, и никаких ошибок не возникало

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между LogCat и отладчиком? И, судя по всему, вы забываете переустанавливать `PendingIntent`. Почитайте тот же StackOverflow, там довольно много подобных тем.

Comment: Я только что проверил через отладчик, и ничего. Про PendingIntent я прочитал, нашёл данную проблему в StackOverflow, все PendingIntent обнавляются в методе onUpdate. Тем не менее проблема осталась. Во всех прочитанных мной проблемах было описано, что такая беда происходит, когда система освобождает память, пока виджет не используется. Но данная проблема может возникнуть через день, или через два дня, или больше. Думаю, за этот период система скидывала мой виджет не раз. Почему же тогда в эти самые "разы" виджет не падает?

Comment: Увидев фразу "зависает не по моей вине", сразу возник вопрос: зачем вы тогда пишите об этом сюда(?) - шлите доказательства на багтрекер Google Android, раз вы уверены;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена, необходимо было в XML-файле (файл описания виджета) установить время, через которое будет обновляться виджет, а иначе он не обновляется и виснет. Это очень странно, т.к. данное обновление виджета необязательно. Я не уверен, но скорее всего это баг системы

**Обновление**

Вы не совсем поняли суть проблемы. Речь шла не об обновлении через интернет, а об обновлении самого виджета через определённый промежуток времени (это обновлении просто перезапускает виджет и обновляет все элементы на нём), Android имеет "слабось" удалять из оперативной памяти приложения, виджеты и т.д., когда эта память ему необходима для других нужд, в таких случаях, когда нам опять понадобится виджет, система опять его запускает, а точнее, обновляет.

Comment: А что там было ДО исправления? У меня вот, андроидный планшет только с WiFi. Поэтому обновляюсь я только оттуда. Когда WiFi выключен, обновлений просто не происходит, и ничего не зависает. Похоже, что это не баг системы, а баг приложения, а точнее - его обновления.